# In UNO, is it legal to throw a Draw 4 card that you just picked up on purpose?

Tags: uno

1. A player decides to draw from the draw pile instead of playing one of his cards (he has a color matching card).
2. He draws a `Wild Draw 4` card and he plays it.

Can the next player challenge him because the play is illegal?

According to [official rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf)

> NOTE: if you suspect that a `Wild Draw 4` card has been played on you
>   illegally (i.e. the player has a matching card), then you may
>   challenge that player. The challenged player must show you their hand.
>   If guilty, the challenged player must draw the 4 cards instead of you. [...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the play is illegal. It doesn't matter that the card was just drawn; it is still prohibited.